# Trouble tapping elements or screen coordinates in RELP / UITest in iOS Xamarin Forms project

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I am working on a Xamarin Forms application (only supporting IOS at this stage) and am wanting to add some UI tests to the solution. Following the standard approach recommended (eg https://www.codetraveler.io/2018/05/22/creating-uitests-for-xamarin-forms-apps-part-1/) I can get the app to launch in the Simulator and start a REPL session/take screenshots.

Once the app has loaded, the user is shown a screen with some information that they dismiss by swiping right to left or tapping the "next" button. The REPL can identify the elements on the screen correctly, but the "next" button (or any other element for that matter) does not react to the tap command. Calling the following code:

```
app.Tap("next");
```

results in the message:

```
Tapping element matching Marked("next") at coordinates [ 689.25, 53.75 ].
```

However nothing actually changes in the simulator. I have tried interacting with a variety of other elements or query selectors (eg using app.Marked..), and have also tried tapping the coordinates using app.TapCoordinates(); nothing seems to react in the open simulator session.

Interestingly, the command

```
app.SwipeRightToLeft();
```

DOES register correctly and causes the splash screen to be dismissed in the simulator.

I have tried setting up a blank test project using XF 4.1 and this seems to work fine, but I don't believe the version of XF could be the issue here, more like a simulator setting. The "Enable UI Automation" setting in the Developer tab is already enabled..

```
- Solution: 
  Xamarin.Forms 2.5.1

- Solution.IOS: 
  Xamarin.Forms 2.5.1
  Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent 0.21.8

- Solution.UITest: 
  NUnit: 2.7
  NUnitTestAdapter: 2.2.0 (not sure this is needed?)
  Xamarin.UITest 3.0.0

- Simulator: iPad Pro (12.9 inch) (3rd gen) iOS 12.2
```

Answer (score 2):

So what is happening is it appears to be scaling the app incorrectly on the larger iPad sizes (anything greater than 9.7 inch)

Calling:

```
app.TapCoordinates(689.25 * 1.3, 53.75 * 1.4)
```

has the desired effect.

I'm happy to just continue testing on smaller devices, but it would be great to find out why the scaling issue exists in the first place, and how to fix it.

Related:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113639/app-tap-wrong-coordinates-on-ipad

Comment: Sadly, I won't be able to tell you why you have this scaling problem, but you could try circumvent it, if its worth the trouble.
Tapping coordinates is almost always a bad idea, for a lot of reasons. What you could try is to find if the wrong coordinates have a fixed offset. If they do, you can grab the coordinates from your elements and add the offset to it, before tapping. That way, you'll be tapping your coordinates in a dynamic way.

Comment: Yeah for sure I posted that to provide more context to the problem. In the end we just opted to test on the 9.7 inch iPad instead, since the device type wasn't particularly important for us. It's just strange that it doesn't seem to be a particularly common issue, but perhaps not many people are testing on large iPads...